# How to monitor a UIViewController for the removal of a UITouch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitouch

[image]

I want to be aware of touch movements inside a UIViewController even it happens on it's deepest child view. As the internal views may be added individually on to Base UIViewController, simply using `touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` or other touch events won't(and doesn't) work by forwarding them to `super`.

Trying to target a specific view through a loop in subviews or responder chain of `Base UIViewController` didn't work as a general solution too.

Is using a custom UIWindow to get all touch events a must? Aren't there any possible solutions?

Summary: I want to know if a touch entered and exited any views on the attached picture. (All views are touchEnabled and I cannot disable it as there are items on those views those must be touchable.)

Comment: It's the age-old annoyance of "passing through touches" right?

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, I am at least trying to find a solution in current context.

Comment: That's why gesture recognizers have been invented, ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at UITouch event's (events that represent the presence or movement of a finger on the screen for a particular event):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html